# C# What is the best way to get the index of an object in a OrderedDictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my `OrderedDictionary` I want to replace an object. I saw that the `OrderedDictionary` has a method called `Insert()`. So, I thought when I get the index of the object I want to replace, I remove that object with `RemoveAt()` and then insert the new object with the `Insert()` method.

But... I need to figure out what the index is of the object I want to replace. Should I simply use a for loop or is there a better way?

Some background information: This piece of code is put into a method. And the method can be called multiple times in a for loop in another method.

Comment: Do you know the key of the object that you want to replace?

Comment: Yes I know. That's why Steve Townsends answer helps me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the key of the target entry you can do it like this:

```
myOrderedDictionary["keyToReplace"] = "modifiedValue";
```

Otherwise, you will have to loop to locate the target before replacing it.

If you only have the target object in hand you can gets its index by looping through the `Values` field, but be aware that it's legal for there to be duplicates here (though not in `Keys`).

Comment: haha that easy. I thought it was read only. Guess I was wrong =]

Comment: @Martijn: If it was read-only, how could you expect to use `RemoveAt` and `Insert`?