# How do I get a index from a OrderedDictionary in C# by key?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm inserting values into an `OrderedDictionary` and need a way to obtain the index for a given key. Is this possible?

```cs
var groups = new OrderedDictionary();
groups.Add("group1", true); 
...
var pos = someFunc(groups, "group1");
// do something with `pos`
```

Comment: Note this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872193/c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-object-in-a-ordereddictionar but I actually do need to get the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to get the index, you could write an extension method to return the index:

```
public static int IndexOfKey(this OrderedDictionary dictionary, object keyToFind)
{
    int currentIndex = 0;
    foreach (var currentKey in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        if (currentKey.Equals(keyToFind)) return currentIndex;
        currentIndex++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var groups = new OrderedDictionary();
groups.Add("group1", true);
groups.Add("group2", true);

Console.WriteLine(groups.IndexOfKey("group2")); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```cs
var groups = new OrderedDictionary();
var group = "group1";

if (groups.Contains(group))
{
    var pos = groups[group];
} else
{
    var values = new int[groups.Count];
    groups.Values.CopyTo(values, 0);
    var pos = values.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Last() + 1;
    groups.Add(group, pos); 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused -- your dictionary with this implementation appears to simply track (as the value) the position within the dictionary that existed when the element was added(?).  I don't see how this could be functional or useful.  What happens when a value is added that isn't the maximum of the ordered set?

Comment: @KirkWoll assuming keys aren't removed or inserted, element insertion order will track the index. For my purposes, this is always the case.